# How create function filter PostgreSQL to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, function, filter, case-when

How create function [filter](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) PostgreSQL to MySQL?

> I tried as follows, but failed:

```
select
    CASE WHEN statusstorie = false and statusTwentyFive = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal' THEN count(*) ELSE 0 END as "25%",
    CASE WHEN statusstorie = false and statusFifty = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal' THEN count(*) ELSE 0 END as "50%",
    CASE WHEN statusstorie = false and statusSeventyFive = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal' THEN count(*) ELSE 0 END as "75%",
    CASE WHEN statusstorie = false and statusOneHundred = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal' THEN count(*) ELSE 0 END as "100%"
from goals
```

> PSQL Example:

```
select
    count(*) filter(where statusstorie = false and statusTwentyFive = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal')  "25%",
    count(*) filter(where statusstorie = false and statusFifty = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal') "50%",
    count(*) filter(where statusstorie = false and statusSeventyFive = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal') "75%",
    count(*) filter(where statusstorie = false and statusOneHundred = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal') "100%"
from goals
```

*Note: If possible I would like to replicate the function to MySQL*

`CREATE FUNCTION filter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
select
    sum(CASE WHEN statusstorie = false and statusTwentyFive = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "25%",
    sum(CASE WHEN statusstorie = false and statusFifty = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "50%",
    sum(CASE WHEN statusstorie = false and statusSeventyFive = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "75%",
    sum(CASE WHEN statusstorie = false and statusOneHundred = true and category not in ('goals') and space = 'personal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "100%"
from goals
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much, do you think it is possible to replicate the function to mysql?

Comment: Something like `CREATE FUNCTION filter()`

Comment: @LuisHenrique  I do not think so because you need to pass in the row as well as the expression to evaluate.